# how to change my rectangles to an image of a bird for my flappy bird game

Tags: java, image, netbeans, rectangles, flappy-bird-clone

> I have a rectangle to represent my bird, i used a tutorial for my bird and pipes but i understand that the Rectangle class has x,y,width and height as its parameters. I am not too sure how to replicate that using an image. My main issue is finding a way to replace the bird "rectangle" with an image without effecting the code.
> All the code related to bird as a rectangle:

```
public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener,MouseListener, KeyListener {

    public static FlappyBird flappybird;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    //object to call methods from Renderer
    public static FlappyBirdUI1 render;
    public static Rectangle bird;
   
  public static  int in, bmotion,scores;
    public boolean gameOver;
    public boolean started;
    
    
    public ArrayList<Rectangle> pipes;
    public static GameOverTest Gover= new GameOverTest();
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
     

    public FlappyBird() {
        
        JPanel jpanel= new JPanel();
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);// used to ensure it repaints throught a schedule timer
        render = new FlappyBirdUI1();

        jframe.add(render);
        
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        //jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        jframe.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.addMouseListener(this);


         
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        
        //using a rectangle as the "bird"
        //REPLACE WITH IMAGE OF BIRD
        bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
        
        pipes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);

        // gsettings.setBounds(0, HEIGHT, 30, 25);
        
        timer.start();
    }
    
   
    
   


    public void jump(){
        
        
        if (gameOver){
             bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 20, 20);
             
        pipes.clear();
        bmotion=0;
        scores=0; 
        
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);
        addpipe(true);
        
            gameOver=false;
        }
        if(!started){
            started=true;
        }else if(!gameOver){
            if(bmotion>0){
                bmotion=0;
            }
               bmotion-=10;    
        }
    }
    
`
```

> here is the rest of my code to give an understanding of how often it is used and to show the need for an x,y,width and height.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    in++;
    //speed of repaint / moving forwrd
    int speed = 10;
    if (started == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pipes.size(); i++) {
            Rectangle pipe = pipes.get(i);
            pipe.x -= speed;

        }
        if (in % 2 == 0 && bmotion < 15) {
            bmotion += 2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pipes.size() - 1; i++) {
            Rectangle pipe = pipes.get(i);

            //x+width is the amnt of the screen he pipe takes
            if (pipe.x + pipe.width < 0) {
                pipes.remove(pipe);
                if (pipe.y == 0) {
                    addpipe(false);
                }

            }
        }
        bird.y += bmotion;

        //colon is like a while there are more objects in the Rectangle pipe arraylist etc
        for (Rectangle pipe : pipes) {
            
            if(pipe.y==0&& bird.x+ bird.width /2 > pipe.x+pipe.width /2-10 && bird.x+bird.width/2 < pipe.x+pipe.width/2+10 )
            {
                scores++;
        }
            
            if (pipe.intersects(bird)) {

                gameOver = true;
                bird.x= pipe.x-bird.width;
                
                
                Gover.show();
                
                
                started=false;
            }
        }

        //if you go out of the screen
        //120 is the white part
        if (bird.y > HEIGHT - 120 || bird.y < 0) {

            gameOver = true;
        }
        
        
        if(bird.y+bmotion> HEIGHT-120){
            bird.y=HEIGHT-120-bird.height;
        }
    }
    
    render.repaint();

    //
}

void repaint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //replace with clouds
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 200, WIDTH, 200);

    //the specific coordinates of the bird must be filled 
    g.setColor(Color.pink);
    g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial",12,100));
    if(!started && !gameOver){
    g.drawString("Click to start", 75, HEIGHT/2-80);    
    }
    if(gameOver){
    g.drawString("Game Over!", 75, HEIGHT/2-80);    
    }
    for (Rectangle pipe : pipes) {
        paintPipe(g, pipe); 
    }
    
    if(!gameOver&& started){

       //String score= ""+scores;
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(scores), WIDTH/2 -25, 100);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Replace `g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);` with `g.drawImage` - see [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for information about loading images; see [Drawing an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) for more about drawing an image